# The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to upload file to https server
I have written the below code to upload file to https server.
but its giving error :

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

MY code is as below. Check what is wrong in the code?

```
       try
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                string filePath = filepath;
                webClient.UploadFile(@"https://us.itranscript.net:444/Upload/test.txt", "PUT", filePath);
                webClient.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

        }
```

Help me

Comment: are you sure about the address(upload/test.txt)?

Comment: Really sure? URLs are case-sensitive (other than the host name).

Comment: Is there any pemission issue on server?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I copy paste the link and put it in browser it works fine

Comment: Confirmed same problem. Anybody have any idea what causes this?

Comment: Same here... but it works with smaller files so I suppose it's a file size issue.